# Finding text of html element with Selenium not working c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

For some reason, the following code finds an empty value rather than the text that it should.

```
Assert.AreEqual("Column", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"technical\"]/div/div/dl/dt[3]")).Text);
```

I have used the same idea for other dt elements and they work so I'm confused as to what is going wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure the column is definitely loaded? Have you tried settings a breakpoint at this line, wait for a while and then continue?

Comment: I have added `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));` but still the same result

Comment: Hmm, that's really weird. I think it would be good if you can share some html code from the page, or can you share a public url ?